# Cast shadow on hidden object in eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadowcatcher

Is it possible for me to have an invisible plane but the shadow of a different object still visible on the plane? It is possible in cycles but i dont like the render results because i need screen space reflection in eevee, which isn't in cycles. help Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started with a simple scene, and this node setup (a standard diffuse is currently connected so we can see the default lighting effects)

[image]

If you connect the other node setup, you might see something like this, depending on the placement and power of your lights (Note: make sure alpha blend is enabled for the shadow catcher material);

[image]

Say you've adjusted this multiple value, but the shadow is too light;

[image]

Move this slider up...;

[image]

And turn up this value;

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying what you suggested, I just have one issue so far, where can i find the Multiply node? If i search for it, there are no results.

Comment: Figured it out, its renamed into math. Thank you so much!